# I have that error #1064 in phpmyadmin say Unrecognized statement type. (near "where" at position 46)

Tags: mysql

SELECT * FROM time_on_screen where id='2' AND where date between '2020-10-04' and '2020-10-10'

Comment: Only one WHERE per select is allowed use and,or and bracketing for multiple conditions/filters

Comment: it should be like `select * from time_on_screen where id = '2' and date between '2020-10-04' and '2020-10-10'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one WHERE per select is allowed use and,or and bracketing for multiple conditions/filters

```
SELECT * FROM time_on_screen where id='2' AND (date between '2020-10-04' and '2020-10-10')
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for `select` clause is

`select` - `column filter`
`from`   - `base table/base tables`
`where`  - `initial row fillter`

here only one `where` clause is allowed in a single `select`.

```
select * from time_on_screen where id = '2' and date between '2020-10-04' and '2020-10-10'
```